# Why does `std::conj(double d)` does not return a `double` but a `std::complex<double>`?

Tags: c++, std

For me it would be more natural that `std::conj(double d)` just returns `d` of type `double` because the result is definitely real.

Comment: I had the same problem a long time ago, with a templated function valid for `double` and `complex<double>`, and the necessity to call `conj` in the complex case. I solved it with a local-declared `conj(double)`. Not sure it is the best workaround.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/conj

Comment: "*... because the result is definitely real.*" It's worth noting that real numbers are a strict subset of complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Because `conj` is an operation on complex numbers. It matches the implicit conversion from `double` to `std::complex<double>` which zero initialises the imaginary component.

From cppreference:

> Additional overloads are provided for `float`, `double`, `long double`, and all integer types, which are treated as complex numbers with zero imaginary component.

Comment: The "real conjugate" would be literally just the identity function. And nobody would could it a "conjugate".

Comment: @Useless we do have `std::identity` as of C++20

Comment: Which is a reasonable name for it. I just meant that there's no real-only equivalent to a complex conjugate, and it wouldn't be useful to have something called that.

Comment: Of course, "real conjugate" is the identity but this supports that `std::conj(double d)` should behave as the identity and returns a `double`. I would be interested if there was any discussions or thoughts by the c++ ISO comittee. It is actually also from importance for practical programming if you use a templated Scalar type which can be real or complex (as mentioned also by Damien in the above comment)